# New file recognized as folder

Tags: java, file, directory

```
boolean flag = new
File("C:/Users/Username/somefolder/.../somefolder/somename.ogg").isFile();

System.out.println("isFile: " + flag);
```

Returns:

```
isFile: false
```

I want to appear as a file.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if isFile = true, then its a file.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself here. You want a file, it is a file, it says it's a file... Which part makes you think it is recognized as a folder?

Comment: Sorry, returns false, my fail.

Comment: Maybe this is directory named `somename.ogg`?

Comment: `isFile()` will also return `false` if the file doesn't exist at that path. Are `isDirectory()` or `exists()` returning `true`?

Comment: Try splitting these into 2 lines to get what you want I guess.

Comment: Sorry all, thank you very much alike, had a route with an accent that was the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file needs to exist for `isFile` to return `true`

From the API docs:

> Returns:
>
> true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname
>   exists and is a normal file; false otherwise

Comment: You can create a new file by calling [`File#createNewFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html%23createNewFile%28%29) (that is, make the file exist)

Comment: Sorry all, thank you very much alike, had a route with an accent that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

About [`File#isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile())

> **Returns:**
>
> `true` if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a normal file; `false` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The file path looks like you are trying to get a file from a Windows machine. For Java you need to represent and escape the path separator correctly. Try the following:

```
 boolean flag = new File("C:\\Users\\Username\\somefolder\\somefolder\\somefolder\\somefoldersomefolder\\somefolder\\somefolder\\somename.ogg").isFile();
```

Also if you are using Java 7 and above it might be worth looking at the Path class instead. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html